# Programm is not loading images right

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I'm building an image recognition for uni, but my code doesn't use my pictures correctly. Every time I try and plot my pictures to see if they are actually used by the cnn, `jupyter notebook` plots a white picture.
I'm sure that I use the correct path.

The pictures are 512x512 pixels and I see when plotted that the program uses the 512 pixels, but they are all white.

Now I used

```
img = load_img('Path')
printimgplot = plt.imshow(img)
```

and it still gives me that white "picture" just with the scale on the side. Any ideas where I' am going wrong or what could happen here?

Comment: This probably is related to the settings in the image format used. Try saving the image to another format (.png, .jpg, ...) and see whether that helps.

Comment: Your currently shown code does not even save *any*  picture. Please make sure to provide a [mcve] in case you need help or advise.